# cherrypy.session won't work on Chrome but works on Firefox

Tags: cherrypy

I run a web with CherryPy (version 3.2.0) and use `cherrypy.session` to store session specific data. It works perfectly with Firefox. However, I noticed that cherrypy.session would run in problems on Chrome. Basically, it looks like session variable resets when the consequent pages are being browsed.

I believe my config is set correctly

```
tools.sessions.on = True
tools.sessions.storage_type = "ram"
tools.sessions.storage_path = "/home/dmitry/test/sessions"
tools.sessions.timeout = 60
tools.sessions.name = "test"
```

What can lead to such a browser-specific problem?

Comment: I don't think that you have a session problem. Ensure that there is no javascript-problem with Chrome that could cause this problem (Have a look to the Chrome-Console -> F12)...

Comment: @dimi - If you have figured out, answering your own question helps other people, so please do if you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess by now you've figured out the solution, but one possible cause can be that the development server is running on localhost, and chrome refuses to set cookies. You have to set up exceptions to make it work. Searching Google for this issue brings up some promising results.