# How to stop regenerating cherrpy.session.id for each call

Tags: python, session-cookies, cherrypy

Folks,

I am running one instance of CherryPy (Version 3.2.4) server and for same endpoint, I am printing value of cherrypy.request.cookie and cherrypy.session.id. for 4 subsequent calls:

```
 session_id=ed46544a403a633bc632a9d193a722a6e0cc9088 b0bb3aec2a5858cbd69e0d3933d2852e753725cd
 session_id=b0bb3aec2a5858cbd69e0d3933d2852e753725cd 069564740a1f38fdc8f4721ee759c3ff1f2a12d2
 session_id=069564740a1f38fdc8f4721ee759c3ff1f2a12d2 87cd7af0bd36ec9d9d4b6e6d74f28fb138ddacfc
 session_id=87cd7af0bd36ec9d9d4b6e6d74f28fb138ddacfc 8cbabaa63f09ce601611c4e7d7f9b28522f4d76f
```

If you see each subsequent calls, cherrypy.session.id gets regerated and sent to client, which comes in next request as cherrypy.request.cookie. It means, each time, I am generating a new session id? What option can I use to stop that?

For same user, I want to have same session_id as long as he does not clears his browser cache?

Please help.

EDIT: This is what my config looks like:

```
cherrypy.config.update({                 
    'tools.sessions.on':            True,
    'tools.sessions.timeout':       120  
})
```

Comment: please show your config and session management files.  Also, what version of cherrypy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cherrypy.session['any_string'] = 'some_string'`
 means that saving any data in session does the trick.

Comment: Interesting!  Happy coding!

Comment: Yep, empty session must be the cause. See CherryPy's Session Fixation Protection.

Answer (score 2):

try...

```
    cherrypy.config.update({                 
    'tools.sessions.on':            True,
    'tools.sessions.timeout':       120,
    'tools.sessions.storage_type' : "file",  #or RAM
    'tools.sessions.storage_path' : "/home/site/sessions"
})
```

http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refman/lib/sessions.html

hope this helps!

Comment: I tried both RAM and file for storage_type but CherryPy regenerates the session.id each time.

Comment: Are you using cherrypy.session.regenerate() anywhere?  Are you using Chrome and localhost instead of an IP?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037429/cherrypy-session-wont-work-on-chrome-but-works-on-firefox

Comment: server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0' and server.socket_port=8099 & I don't use regenerate() anywhere. I have read the doc multiple times but stil l unsure of the issue.